# Git pull to www folder after git push

Tags: linux, apache, acl

I would like to pull code to virtual host directory from GIT after a push. The problem is that commit hook runs as git user but the folder of virtual directory on apache is under www-data:www-data.

Is there any possibility to run script as www-data (shell script including git pull and some rm stuff for temp) instead of git user?

Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it *is* possible using `sudo` and defining specific commands, I'd recommend against it: This setup sounds easy to misconfigure or break.

I'd recommend that you have a cron job run a `git pull` every few minutes instead.

Comment: Yes, I have cron job for git pull now. But sometimes is necessary to have code in www folder asap. What is wrong with sudo command?

Comment: Nothing really, you just have to be very careful when configuring it - otherwise you may grant root access to situations and users which aren't supposed to have it.

Comment: For "get it NOW" situations, I'd recommend sshing into your server separately and running the git pull command. Sometimes capistrano or similar software is used to wrap this functionality as a "deploy" script.